# Login Screen returns to login screen

Tags: login, auto-login

After many many reboots in a couple days while experimenting with BIOS settings effecting the speed Hardbrake runs at, today I find after a reboot that I have to type in password to log in - ordinarily I have this disabled.

When I DO enter my password, it goes to a black screen for a bit, then returns. I can log in as guest, which does the same thing (minus the password) and if I use the wrong password, it complains instead of doing the same.

Using the install disc, I see three partitions on my drive, a ~200 MB boot sector, and two 32 GB (one extended) which seem to share the rest of the SSD.

Running FSCK seems to generate tons of errors.

The odd bits: All my background stuff is running - I can access stuff served by Subsonic, and see network shares from my windows machines. I can log in in another terminal and do stuff... I just can't get into the GUI/OS proper.

Sort of at a loss where to start. Would be happy to free drive of errors if I could (I've another machine, I could mount drive over USB and check it), but it seems everything else is working?

edit: Screensaver also seems to kick on, even from fsck's run from the boot menu.

---

i3-2100t, H67 chipset I believe, 12.10, everything's been working fine for the better part of a year. Seen several similar topics, but either they turn out to be something unrelated (fresh install or known graphics issues) or there are no answers. I'm happy to get any logs/info anyone want.

---

Starting to think SSD is corrupted in some way that's preventing booting. Can't get FSCK to complete on it.

update: ran ""fsck -n /dev/mapper/ubunutu-root"" got the answer it was clean.

Ok, here's a copy of my Xorg.0.log.old file:

```
[   340.321] 
X.Org X Server 1.13.0
Release Date: 2012-09-05
[   340.321] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   340.321] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-26-generic i686 Ubuntu
[   340.321] Current Operating System: Linux HBO 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:49:53 UTC 2012 i686
[   340.321] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   340.321] Build Date: 27 November 2012  07:44:37AM
[   340.321] xorg-server 2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   340.321] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[   340.321]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   340.321] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   340.321] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Dec 18 16:34:28 2012
[   340.321] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   340.321] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   340.321] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   340.321] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   340.321] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   340.322] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   340.322] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   340.322] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   340.322] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[   340.322]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   340.322] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   340.322] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   340.322] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   340.322] (II) Loader magic: 0xb7787640
[   340.322] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   340.322]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   340.322]    X.Org Video Driver: 13.0
[   340.322]    X.Org XInput driver : 18.0
[   340.322]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[   340.322] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   340.323] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0102:19da:a166 rev 9, Mem @ 0xfe000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[   340.323] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   340.323] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   340.323] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   340.323] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   340.324] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.324]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[   340.324]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[   340.324] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   340.324] Loading extension GLX
[   340.324] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[   340.324] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[   340.324] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   340.324] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[   340.324] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[   340.324] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   340.324] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   340.324] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   340.324] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.324]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.20.9
[   340.324]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   340.324]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[   340.324] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   340.325] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   340.325] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.325]    compiled for 1.12.99.902, module version = 2.3.2
[   340.325]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   340.325]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[   340.325] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   340.325] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   340.325] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.325]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.5.0
[   340.325]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   340.325]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[   340.325] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   340.325] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   340.325] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.325]    compiled for 1.12.99.902, module version = 0.4.3
[   340.325]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   340.325]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[   340.325] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
    Ivybridge Server (GT2), Haswell Desktop (GT1), Haswell Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell Desktop (GT2+), Haswell Mobile (GT1), Haswell Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell Mobile (GT2+), Haswell Server (GT1), Haswell Server (GT2),
    Haswell Server (GT2+), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT1), Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2+), Haswell SDV Server (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Server (GT2), Haswell SDV Server (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT1), Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2+), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT1),
    Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT1), Haswell ULT Server (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT2+), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT1), Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2+), Haswell CRW Server (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Server (GT2), Haswell CRW Server (GT2+),
    ValleyView PO board
[   340.326] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   340.326] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   340.326] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   340.326] (++) using VT number 7

[   340.326] (II) intel(0): using device path '/dev/dri/card0'
[   340.326] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   340.326] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   340.326] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   340.326] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   340.326] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   340.326] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   340.326] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   340.326]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.0.2
[   340.326]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[   340.326] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   340.326] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   340.326] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[   340.326] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   340.326] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) Sandybridge Desktop (GT1)
```

.....
EDIT FOR BREVITY
.....

```
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.861] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   340.861] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   340.861] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   340.861] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   340.861] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[   340.861] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   340.861] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   340.861] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   340.861] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[   340.861] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.861] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.861] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   340.862] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[   340.862] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.862] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.862] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[   340.862] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.862] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.862] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event12)
[   340.862] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.862] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.862] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event13)
[   340.862] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.862] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event14)
[   340.863] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.863] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front (/dev/input/event15)
[   340.863] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.863] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event7)
[   340.863] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.863] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
[   340.863] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.863] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event9)
[   340.863] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.863] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.863] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0c16:0001 (/dev/input/event5)
[   340.863] (**) HID 0c16:0001: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   340.863] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 0c16:0001'
[   340.863] (**) HID 0c16:0001: always reports core events
[   340.864] (**) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Vendor 0xc16 Product 0x1
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found keys
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Configuring as keyboard
[   340.864] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/input/input5/event5"
[   340.864] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 0c16:0001" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.864] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0c16:0001 (/dev/input/event6)
[   340.864] (**) HID 0c16:0001: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   340.864] (**) HID 0c16:0001: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   340.864] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 0c16:0001'
[   340.864] (**) HID 0c16:0001: always reports core events
[   340.864] (**) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Vendor 0xc16 Product 0x1
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found 13 mouse buttons
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found relative axes
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found x and y relative axes
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found absolute axes
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[   340.864] (--) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Found keys
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Configuring as mouse
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Configuring as keyboard
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Adding scrollwheel support
[   340.864] (**) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   340.864] (**) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   340.864] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.1/input/input6/event6"
[   340.864] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 0c16:0001" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.864] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.864] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: initialized for relative axes.
[   340.864] (WW) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: ignoring absolute axes.
[   340.864] (**) HID 0c16:0001: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   340.864] (**) HID 0c16:0001: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   340.865] (**) HID 0c16:0001: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   340.865] (**) HID 0c16:0001: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   340.865] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0c16:0001 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   340.865] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.865] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   340.865] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[   340.865] (**) Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   340.865] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard'
[   340.865] (**) Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: always reports core events
[   340.865] (**) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   340.865] (--) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0x533
[   340.865] (--) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Found keys
[   340.865] (II) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   340.865] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input2/event2"
[   340.865] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   340.865] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.865] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.865] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.865] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   340.865] (**) Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   340.865] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard'
[   340.866] (**) Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: always reports core events
[   340.866] (**) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[   340.866] (--) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0x533
[   340.866] (--) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Found keys
[   340.866] (II) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   340.866] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input3/event3"
[   340.866] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   340.866] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   340.866] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   340.866] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   340.866] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/event4)
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   340.866] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE'
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: always reports core events
[   340.866] (**) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[   340.866] (--) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2510
[   340.866] (--) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found 3 mouse buttons
[   340.866] (--) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   340.866] (--) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found relative axes
[   340.866] (--) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found x and y relative axes
[   340.866] (II) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Configuring as mouse
[   340.866] (II) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Adding scrollwheel support
[   340.866] (**) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   340.866] (**) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   340.866] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/input/input4/event4"
[   340.866] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[   340.866] (II) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: initialized for relative axes.
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   340.866] (**) PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   340.866] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   340.866] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   340.866] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 22553
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[   341.141] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 22553
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[   341.481] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[   341.482] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[   341.482] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[   346.532] (II) evdev: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Close
[   346.532] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.532] (II) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Close
[   346.532] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.532] (II) evdev: Chicony USB EL Backlit Keyboard: Close
[   346.532] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.532] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Close
[   346.532] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.532] (II) evdev: HID 0c16:0001: Close
[   346.532] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.532] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[   346.533] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.533] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[   346.533] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   346.764] Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I have a stack of notes generated by the command/script
`MYLOG=/media/HBO-RAID/RAID-Storage/MyLog$(date +%T-%d.%m.%y).log; echo '['"code"']' >> ${MYLOG} && uname -a >> ${MYLOG} && lsb_release -a >> ${MYLOG} && for LOGFILE in $(ls /var/log/*.log); do sudo grep -iHw 'segfault\|warning\|error\|critical\|lightdm\|\(WW \)\|\(EE\)' $LOGFILE | tee -a ${MYLOG}; done && echo '['"code"']' >> ${MYLOG}`

Right now I'm thinking permissions or similar. It says I don't have rights to login without password, which I normally have this machine set for.
`/var/log/auth.log:Dec 19 01:06:23 HBO lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "abe"`

Comment: This looks suspicious:
`/var/log/kern.log:Dec 18 23:38:25 HBO kernel: [    4.382811] ACPI Warning: 0x00000460-0x0000047f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.TCOI 1 (20120320/utaddress-251)`  

I WAS playing with the bios. Could I have accidentally turned off something it expects to see?

Answer (score 13):

This happened to me once (or at least something similar did). There should be a file in your home folder called `.Xauthority`; make sure your user has permission to read and write to it. If I remember correctly, you can make yourself it's owner by entering `sudo chown user /home/user/.Xauthority`, where `user` is your username.

Comment: abe@HBO:~$ ls -l .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 abe abe 0 Dec 18 23:44 .Xauthority

Comment: i.e. it was already set up that way. Good idea though. See comment on other post for likely issue?

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank goodness for console browsing :) I used `sudo chown user:user .Xauthority` though, to have it put in the same group as well.

Comment: To do this, bypass the login screen with `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and enter your username/password

Comment: I fixed this by logging in as root and deleting the .Xauthority file in the affected user's home folder. It was regenerated correctly when I logged in as that user.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found this post as the highest ranked answer, so I thought I'd post my resolution.

I had recently change my `~/.profile` to customize my command prompt.  Doing a <kbd>CRTL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to login and removing those profile changes fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When at LightDM (login screen), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login with your accound and then type:

**For Unity**

`sudo apt-get install unity`

**For Gnome**

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

**For Classic Gnome**

`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

Then type `sudo restart lightdm`, choose which session you want from the list and login.

Comment: Install all three? I did [i]just[/i] the Unity one (assuming you meant to do the one I use). It said it was already installed and didn't do anything. Continued on to restart command with same results as before.
When I log in, it said update available (linux headers) which are "held back" if I do an update.

Comment: Ran the other two - after looking at log files (posted above). Gnome-Shell asked GDM or lightdm - selected light. Fallback said I already had latest version. Reinstalled unity, too. restart lightdm gave same results. rebooting, if I see anything different I'll post, otherwise assume still stuck on login screen

Comment: Tried ALL variants after reboot, on main account and guest. All have same behavior.

Comment: `abe@HBO:~$ more .xsession-errors
initctl: Unknown job: lightdm-session
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but gnome-session --session=ubuntu is not supported for Upstart jobs.`

Comment: you can reinstall the previous sessions that are already there by adding `--reinstall` after `apt-get install`